# Understanding example for Improved Policy Iteration for POMDPs

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, pomdp

I was going through [this paper by Hansen](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1997/file/c930eecd01935feef55942cc445f708f-Paper.pdf). This paper proposes policy improvement by first converting set of $\alpha$ vectors into finite state controller and then comparing them to obtain improved policy. The whole algorithm is summmarised as follows:

[image]

Section 4 of this paper explains the algorithm with example. I am unable to get the example, specifically how it forms those states, what are the numbers inside each state and how they are exactly calculated:

[image]